# PHP cookie won't set unless I start session

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

In my script, unless I call `session_start()`, `print_r($_COOKIE)` will display an empty array regardless of how many times the page is refreshed. I am hopping someone has encountered this and could shed more light.

```
//session_start(); // will not set if i remove this
if(!isset($_COOKIE['dvr'])){
    $cookieDN = 'DVR';
    $cookieDV = 2;
    setcookie($cookieDN, $cookieDV, strtotime("today 6:59"),"/foo/","www.domain.com",FALSE,FALSE);
}print_r($_COOKIE); // prints null when session_start() is not called
```

Comment: could be any problem with "DVR" and "dvr"?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

refer this to setup cookies, i think some thing wrong with your 3rd, 4th parameter in setcookie function

and cookies name are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed the link. Updated the case sensitive error DVR and dvr error. But still a mystery to me. I tested on two separate servers.The script runs and sets the cookie on my online server but will not work on the official production server unless i call `session_start()`. And by doing so, cookie will have to be reset on browser lunch again. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You use missing index in array!

use

```
$cookieDN = 'dvr';
```

insted of:

```
$cookieDN = 'DVR';
```

or use

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['DVR'])){
```

insted of :

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['dvr'])){
```

PHP is case sensitive!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, still not setting. I tested on two servers, works on one but not work on main production server unless session_start() is called. Meaning I have to reset cookie every time the browser is launched even though cookie has not expired